# pwntools Python module doesn't work in python2 but works in python3

Tags: python-import, python-2.x, importerror, pwntools, python-3.8

I have a python2 script I want to run with the [pwntools python module](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools) and I tried running it using:

> python test.py

But then I get:

> File "test.py", line 3, in 
>       from pwn import *
>   ImportError: No module named pwn

But when I try it with python3, it gets past that error but it runs into other errors because it's a python2 script. Why does pwntools not work when I run it with python2 and can I get my script to run without porting the whole thing to python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say for sure but it looks like you installed pwntools for python3 and not for python2. Packages are not shared between python versions. if you run `python2 -m pip install --user pwntools` and then try to run with python2 does it work?

Comment: I get errors when installing it: https://pastebin.com/CGAAW4sM I also tried it with sudo but it has the same log. I've tried running the script after trying to install it but I get the same error.

Comment: are you running windows? Last I knew pwntools doesn't support windows. you might try pwintools https://github.com/masthoon/pwintools or what I'd recommend would be to build a linux vm in virtualbox and run the script in there if possible.

Comment: https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/install.html confirmed that pwntools doesn't support windows.

Comment: No I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.6. I’ll try the Linux virtual machine though thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yeah even I had faced this issue. Try installing pwntools using `sudo pip install pwntools`.